# Permission Denied on Select tables after giving Select permission to new user in Azure Postgres SQL single server database

Tags: postgresql, azure-postgres-database

I have Azure postgresql single server database which I need to give read permission to a newly created user.

```
CREATE USER "test@hostName" PASSWORD 'XXXX';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "test" TO "test@hostName";
```

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
FOR USER pgadmin
IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT   ON TABLES TO  "test@hostName" ;
```

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
WHERE grantee = 'test@hostName';
```

This is the result
[image]

But when this user executes a select query Permission Denied message appears and not allowed to select. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Below the result for pg_class for the selected table. It shows that pgadmin has full rights and required user has read access.

this is the result I got when running the query:
`SELECT relacl FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tablename';`

result:

```
"{pgadmin=a*r*w*d*D*x*t*/pgadmin,""\""d_reader@adb-psql-tckt-history\""=r/pgadmin""}"
```

Comment: What are the results of `\z tablename` when connected with `psql`?

Comment: can see all the tables in the schema. 
can view columns details
But cant read data or use select queries, getting the above permission denied error

Comment: Table owneer is pgadmin

Comment: What are the results of `\z tablename` when connected with `psql`? If you don't want to connect with `psql`, please show the result of `SELECT relacl FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tablename';`. [Edit] the question and add the information there. Avoid images.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Above I added the result for relacl column. It shows the access being set. But still when selecting it shows access denied. Let me know if you know how to fix this. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I asked for no images. And you smeared red color over the interesting parts. If you cannot share this information, hire professional help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added the result. you may see the result in the question. Thanks for the help. Let me know

Comment: You granted the `SELECT` privilege to a role called `"\"d_reader@adb-psql-tckt-history\"` (including all the double quotes and backslashes). Is that what you intended?

Comment: No. I want d_reader@adb-psql-tckt-history. this output is how the tool shows the result.

Comment: Ah, I see. That user will be able to `SELECT` from the table. You must have tried with a different user.

Comment: No. that user cannot select. That is the issue. When user runs the select statement. gives permission denied as the result. But he can log and connect to database, view table definition. @LaurenzAlbe Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't believe you. But you conveniently deleted the name of the table from the image with the error message, so I cannot be sure what is going on. Perhaps you are actually selecting from a view, or there is a rewrite rule involved. You'll have to come up with a complete, self-contained test case so that we can reproduce what you are seeing.